# Calculate bearing between two latlong flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

How to calculate bearing between two latitude and longitude, I need to use this in google map for icon rotation.

Answer (score 1):

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

This geolocator has the provision to calculate bearing between two location.

```
double calculatedRotation = Geolocator.bearingBetween(
            start.latitude,
            start.longitude,
            end.latitude,
            end.longitude);
```